# Cannot create a timestamp with VBA by using a called function

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following that creates a copy of a range.

```
Dim lastColumn As Long
lastColumn = wks.Cells(2, wks.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastColumn = Application.Max(lastColumn + 1, wks.Columns("T").Column)

With wks.Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(lastrow, 5)) ' This is the range I need to copy in my case
    Dim columnOffset As Long
    columnOffset = lastColumn - .Columns(1).Column
    Call Timestamp(wks.Range(Cells(1, columnOffset)))
    .Copy
    .Offset(0, columnOffset).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
```

And I call the following function to create a timestamp above the copied cells, but I get an empty cell above the copied cells

```
Public Function Timestamp(Reference As Range)
If Reference.Value <> "" Then
Timestamp = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
Else
Timestamp = ""
End If
End Function
```

What I am doing wrong?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the cell, you aren't returning the value from the function. Try something like this with the existing code

```
wks.Range(Cells(1, columnOffset)).value = Timestamp(wks.Range(Cells(1, columnOffset)))
```

You could simplify this, not sure if the function is entirely needed, but it doesn't really matter. Something like should work too:

```
if wks.Range(Cells(1, columnOffset)).value <> "" then wks.Range(Cells(1, columnOffset)).value = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

Comment: I placed the if wks.Range(Cells(1, columnOffset)).value <> "" then wks.Range(Cells(1, columnOffset)).value = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss") after the .Offset(0, columnOffset).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats in my initial copy sub and it makes all initial cells 0 and the pasted cells 0 as well

Comment: Check you are setting the range correctly. What is the value for columnOffset? Also, you may want to set the range like: `wks.Range(wks.Cells(1, columnOffset)).value` you should be explicit defining which worksheet you are updating.

Answer (score 0):

I change it to the following

```
If wks.Cells(1, lastColumn).Value = "" Then
wks.Cells(1, lastColumn).Value = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
End If
```

So I have the following

```
Dim lastColumn As Long
lastColumn = wks.Cells(2, wks.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastColumn = Application.Max(lastColumn + 1, wks.Columns("T").Column)

With wks.Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(lastrow, 5)) ' This is the range I need to copy in my case
    Dim columnOffset As Long
    columnOffset = lastColumn - .Columns(1).Column
    If wks.Cells(1, lastColumn).Value = "" Then
    wks.Cells(1, lastColumn).Value = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    End If
    .Copy
    .Offset(0, columnOffset).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
```